# Script to match regex fails with a syntax error on a specific version of bash

Tags: bash

I have a script to match a pattern, and if it matches, I used the match to append to a variable.

My script works on Bash `v3.2.57` and fails on `v4.3.30`.

Could someone tell me what is wrong with the second `if`condition that matches a pattern here?

`#!/bin/sh
if [ -f .file-to-read ]; then
  while read p; do
    echo "yes"
    if [[ $p =~ "@user/"(.+)"@"[0-9]+"."[0-9]+"."[0-9]+ ]]
    then
      var="$var<@user/${BASH_REMATCH[1]}|$p>\\n"
    fi
  done < .file-to-read
fi`

The error message is

`Syntax error: "(" unexpected (expecting "then")`

Comment: Why the creative quoting? Why not just comply with extended `man 3 regex`? The quotes are not wrong, they just make it a bit wonky to read. Don't know what is in `.file-to-read`, but `read` without `-r` will mangle backslashes. Will have to look to see if there were any changes in `regex` handling between bash 3/4 -- don't recall any offhand.

Comment: ( it is unrelated though ), but show us a single line you want to match

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the issue. The problem was the file was being executed in `#!/bin/sh` when it should have been `#!/bin/bash`